# QGIS Workflow Problem

Tags: qgis, shapefile, spatialite, workflow

I have 3 SpatiaLite layers (one without geometry but with fields that need to be filtered, one with points and one with polygons, both without any non-geometry fields) that need to be combined to a single one, i.e. a left outer join is needed. Also, some filtering on the attributes needs to be done (in particular, a certain time range needs to be filtered). Apart from that, I also need to spatially filter the layers with points and polygons:

- All the points *inside* a certain boundary (a single polygon only available as a SHP) need to be retained
- All the polygons that *overlap* with this certain boundary need to be retained, i.e. both the polygons fully inside the boundary and also those which are only partially inside.

The **main problem** is that all of these layers contain quite a lot of data (i.e. >800mb) and it is quite tedious to trial-and-error the different possibilities. That is why I am asking what work process I should follow:

- Filtering and joining the SpatiaLite data with the Database manager in QGIS and then doing the clipping or whatever geometry function is needed for the above process? Could I actually do the clipping or whatever geometry function also directly in SpatiaLite, given that the boundary is only available as a SHP?
- Doing the clipping or whatever geometry function is needed first, which yields a shapefile, but how do I join them afterwards?

Actually, I am pretty lost / don't know the QGIS functions well enough.

Comment: Have you tried SpatiaLite SQL queries to filter? I'd suggest rewriting your question into bite-sized chunks as it will help formulate a workflow.

Comment: please add the schemas of your tables. "both without any non-geometry fields" is confusing me because how could they be joined with the non-spatial layer then? is there anything preventing you from importing the Shapefile into Spatialite?

Comment: Sorry, this question can be considered as closed. I have found a totally different workflow/didn't really care in the end, anymore. Thanks though.